# Gradle variable in buildscript is null for Maven repository credentials

Tags: gradle, groovy

For context, my ultimate goal here is to inject Maven credentials used for buildscript plugins via environment variables or using the Maven settings.xml.

I created this buildscript closure to fetch the creds:

```
buildscript {
  ext.nexusCreds = {
    def id = "releases"
    def username = System.getenv("NEXUS_USER")
    def password = System.getenv("NEXUS_PASSWORD")

    if (!(username && password && username.trim() && password.trim())) {
      File mavenSettings = new File("${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/settings.xml")
      if (mavenSettings.exists()) {
        def xmlSlurper = new XmlSlurper()
        def settings = xmlSlurper.parse(mavenSettings)
        username = settings.servers.children().find { it.id == id }.username
        password = settings.servers.children().find { it.id == id }.password
      }
    }

    println("Username: $username")
    println("Password: $password")
    [username: username, password: password]
  }()
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
      url "http://nexus.ourStagingEnv.com/content/repositories/releases/"
      credentials {
        username nexusCreds.username
        password nexusCreds.password
      }
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath group: 'com.myPlugin', name: 'myPlugin', version: '1.0.0'
  }
}
```

The problem is, when the build gets to the custom "maven" closure, it seems to think "username" is null:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myProject'.
> Could not find method username() for arguments [deployment] on Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.
```

Note that the "username" and "password" variables both get printed as non-null within the "nexusCreds" closure (I have these set in my settings.xml).

Here's the weird part:
If I hardcode those values within the "nexusCreds" closure, everything works fine.

```
ext.nexusCreds = {
    def id = "releases"
    def username = System.getenv("NEXUS_USER")
    def password = System.getenv("NEXUS_PASSWORD")

    if (!(username && password && username.trim() && password.trim())) {
      File mavenSettings = new File("${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/settings.xml")
      if (mavenSettings.exists()) {
        def xmlSlurper = new XmlSlurper()
        def settings = xmlSlurper.parse(mavenSettings)
        username = settings.servers.children().find { it.id == id }.username
        password = settings.servers.children().find { it.id == id }.password
      }
    }

    username = "myUsername"
    password = "myPassword"
    println("Username: $username")
    println("Password: $password")
    [username: username, password: password]
  }()
```

Why does that first code block fail, but hardcoding it works? Is there something I'm missing here around Groovy or Gradle behavior around these closures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh. Found the issue. It turned out to be a problem in my settings.xml parsing. username and password were XML nodes, not Strings. The fix was:

```
username = settings.servers.children().find { it.id == id }.username.toString()
password = settings.servers.children().find { it.id == id }.password.toString()
```